# Testflight and RubyMotion

Tags: ruby, rubymotion, testflight, motion

I'm working with RubyMotion and now integrated Testflight, but it seems the checkpoints doesn't work. I guess I did something wrong, but I'm not sure how to fix it.

This is my Ruby code inside one of my files:

```
TestFlight.passCheckpoint("Synced all data");
```

Cheers!

PS: Other topics doesn't seem to have any real answers, so that's why I'm asking it again.

Comment: Do you have a call to `TestFlight.takeOff()` in your AppDelegate?

Comment: Could you post a more complete example? :)

Comment: @Silasj I didn't will try that first.